# Arduino Ethernet Shield Client.connect returns error code -5

Tags: arduino

I have a brand new Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) on [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and have worked through many (non-Ethernet) examples without any issues, until I tried to use the Ethernet shield.

Using the provided EthernetClient example, I get a connection failed. The return code is -5 (and I could only find answers for -4 through 1).

```cpp
/*
  Web client

 This sketch connects to a website (http://www.google.com)
 using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield.

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13

 Created 18 Dec 2009
 Modified 9 Apr 2012
 by David A. Mellis

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield

byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0x4E, 0x71 };;
char server[] = "google.com"; // Google

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // Start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
  // Give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

    Serial.println("Obtaining local IP address");
    IPAddress myIPAddress = Ethernet.localIP();
    Serial.println(myIPAddress);
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  int ret = client.connect(server, 80);
  if (ret == 1) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
  }
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("Connection failed");
    Serial.println(ret);
    Serial.println(client.status());
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // If there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // If the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // Do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

The results are always:

```
Connecting...
Obtaining local IP address
192.168.0.7
Connection failed
-5
0

disconnecting.
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a wireshark capture on the server to see what traffic - if any - is arriving?

Comment: No traffic makes it to the server, but my router does lease an address.

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem and I don't know how to solve it..

Comment: I debugged a lot for the same problem using Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this helped, but adding a delay after the Serial is intialized, before beginning Ethernet, and also increasing the delay before using Ethernet seemed to work.

```
/*
  Web client

 This sketch connects to a website (http://www.google.com)
 using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield. 

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13

 created 18 Dec 2009
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by David A. Mellis

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield

byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0x4E, 0x71 };;
char server[] = "google.com"; // Google

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
delay(5000);
  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

    Serial.println("Obtaining local IP");
    IPAddress myIPAddress = Ethernet.localIP(); 
    Serial.println(myIPAddress);
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  int ret = client.connect(server, 80);
  if (ret == 1) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    Serial.println(ret);
    Serial.println(client.status());
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available 
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would love someone to tell me why this works, I can recreate the issue by removing those delays, and heal it by inserting them back in.  I would think the while(!Serial) .   ALSO while(!client) seems to never pass, so I just use a long delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the server IP address as it is shown on the [Arduino Reference Page](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnect):

```cpp
byte server[] = { 64, 233, 187, 99 }; // Google
```

Try a couple different example programs.  There have been some revisions with the move to IDE 1.0 that could affect compatibility.

Comment: Anyway, using a host name doesnt work either, see my comment on Jason's answr.

Comment: I didn'nt mean a specific IP Address.  I meant try using an array of bytes instead of `IPAddress ....`

Answer (score 0):

That Google IP address (173.194.33.104) is not valid now. Try to use 74.125.226.242 instead:

```
IPAddress server(74,125,226,242); // Google
```

And before your try it on Arduino, ensure your can open this IP address in your browser:

```
 http://74.125.226.242
```

Comment: yeah, have tried a numer of IPs, updated above to use a hostname.